# How do I center a single title heading in LaTeX?

Tags: sectioning

```
        \documentclass{article}
        \title{Gauss's Law}
        \author{anon}
        \date{\vspace{-5ex}}
        \begin{document}
        \maketitle
        \noindent
        $\Phi_E$ = Electric Flux \\ E = Electric Field \\ Q = Point Charge \\ $\phi$ = Angle between $\vec E$ and normal 
        \\normal = a normal is an object such as a line, ray, or vector that is perpendicular to a given object
        
        \section*{BASIC FORMULA}
        $$\Phi_E = \oint Ecos\phi ~dA = \frac{Q_{encl}} {\epsilon_0}$$
        
        \section*{basic ideas}
    
    \end{document}
```

So this is my code. I am very new to `LaTeX` and I have searched online, however I can't seem to find how to center a single heading. I want the basic formula title to be centered, however I don't want the rest to be.

Comment: You can either modify `\maketitle,` or not use it at all.  In either case you might want to look up the source for `\maketitle` in article.cls (base folder).

Answer (score 1):

I have edited a bit your code. First, I got rid of the double dollars that do not represent the correct syntax in LaTeX. You can see in fact this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to). Next if you want one section to be centered with respect to another you need to use the command `{\centering \section*{......}}`. And you will have the section placed in the middle. All the others will be on the left. I don't know if you want all the sections centered. In this case you should to add to the preamble

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\centering}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Gauss's Law}
\author{anon}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\noindent
    $\Phi_E$ = Electric Flux \\ E = Electric Field \\ Q = Point Charge 
    \\ $\phi$ = Angle between $\vec E$ and normal 
    \\normal = a normal is an object such as a line, ray, or vector that is perpendicular to a given object   
    
    {\centering \section*{BASIC FORMULA}} 
    \[\Phi_E = \oint E\cos\phi ~dA = \frac{Q_{\textup{encl}}} {\epsilon_0}\]
    
    \section*{basic ideas}

\end{document}
```

[image]